# How to create a excel file and need to save in root directory?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, reports, core, varien

I tried to create to a excel file and need to save that created file some places.

```
$filename = 'request_quote.xlsx';
        $exportData[0]['product_id'] = 123;
        $exportData[0]['product_name'] = 123;
        $exportData[0]['vendor_name'] = 123;

        $data[0]=array($this->__("Product ID"),$this->__("Product Name"),$this->__("Vendors"));

        $i=1;
        foreach($exportData as $key=>$value){
            $data[$i]=array($value['product_id'],$value['product_name'],$value['vendor_name']);
            $i++;
        }

    $xmlObj = new Varien_Convert_Parser_Xml_Excel();
    $xmlObj->setVar('single_sheet', $filename);
    $xmlObj->setData($data);
    $xmlObj->unparse();
    $content = $xmlObj->getData();

    $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($filename,$content);
```

When i use above code, its forced me to download the excel file.

now my question is how to save that file in folder or root directory?

Note:
not a csv file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`prepareDownloadResponse()` is used to declare headers and content type in response for file download from browser.

So you need to change the code

**from**

```
$this->_prepareDownloadResponse($filename,$content);
```

**to**

```
$io = new Varien_Io_File();
$io->setAllowCreateFolders(true);
$io->open(array('path' => Mage::getBaseDir()));
if ($io->fileExists('filename.Extension') && !$io->isWriteable('filename.Extension')) {

        // file does not exist or is not readable
        return;
}

$io->streamOpen('filename.Extension');
$io->streamWrite($content);
$io->streamClose();
```

to write the file to `filename.Extension` in the root directory (`Mage::getBaseDir()`)

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();

$products->addAttributeToSelect('category_ids');

$fp = fopen('exports.csv', 'w+');

$csvHeader = array('id',"sku", "category_ids");

fputcsv( $fp, $csvHeader,",");

foreach ($products as $product){

    $sku = $product->getSku();
    $ID = $product->getId();
    $categoryIds = implode('|', $product->getCategoryIds());//change the category separator if needed
    fputcsv($fp, array($ID, $sku, $categoryIds), ",");
}

fclose($fp);
```

it will generate excel file in root directory